# Question about chaining multiple "not" in "if x or y or z"

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

Good day, Im currently trying to write a simple programm, as part of my courses practice, which plays rock paper scissors with the user. I have completed the assignment itself but wanted to flesh it out a little and tried adding the following piece of code, which is supposed to check for misspelled variants of the word and let the user know their input was invalid:

```
elif not b=="schere" or b=="stein" or b=="papier":
    print("Zu dumm zum tippen!?")
```

now my problem is that, in this form, the code doesn't actually work. While it correctly acknowledges "schere" as being a correct input and eeffectively "does nothing" in that case, it blocks other input as being invalid. This makes sense to me, as the code turns the input "stein" or "papier" into a True, which triggers the print. So far, so good?

However, I cannot seem to figure out how to properly chain these together. If I place additional "not" behind each or, as I would assume it should work, it no longer seems to do anything properly and flags ANY input as incorrect and prints the above phrase. The same malfunction occurs when I "only" try adding another not to one of the "or"s. Is it even possible to chain these together as I am trying to? I tried googling and searching here but all I find are posts / tutorials regarding chaining multiple and / or statements, but nothing about negating these.

IIRC we are working with python 3.5

Comment: `not` has a greater priority than `==` and `or` operators, but you'll want to apply those `==` and `or` operators first and only then apply `not` to that result. So put parentheses around the expression that you want to have the `not` of. You could also look into the `not in` operator.

Comment: " If I place additional "not" behind each or, as I would assume it should work, it no longer seems to do anything properly " because that isn't how the negation of a disjunction works! Learn [de Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)!

Comment: Thanks alot trincot for the explanation and solution! and thanks to juanpa for the resosurce regarding de Morganss laws!

Answer (score 1):

Because:

```
 not b == "schere" or b == "stein" or b == "papier"
```

is equivalent to:

```
(not b == "schere") or b == "stein" or b == "papier"
```

Because [`not` has a higher precedence than `or`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence).

A simple solution:

```
not (b == "schere" or b == "stein" or b == "papier")
```

Note, if you wanted the equivalent logic by distributing the `not`, you have to use [De Morgan's laws!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

The equivalent would be:

```
(not b == "schere") and (not b == "stein") and (not b == "papier")
```

i.e., `not (P or Q)` is equivalent to `(not P) and (not Q)`

Comment: Note: you should use `!=` instead of `not ==`…

Comment: @deceze definitely in this particular case